# Change url for a route in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a search scope for my users with the following route:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get :search
  end
end
```

This however generates `/users/search` as url. I would like to have `/search` as url. I tried the following:

```
get '/search', as: :search
get '/search' => 'users#search', as: :search
get :search, to: 'users#search', as: :search
```

They don't seem to work since I keep getting routing errors. What would be the correct way to write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work (without the leading '/') :

```
resources :users
get 'search' => 'users#search', as: :search
```

The named helpers for this route will be `search_path` and `search_url`

Answer (score 0):

you can also use match:

```
match "/search", to: "users#search", via: "get"
```

Comment: Yes, but `get '/search', to: 'users#search'` is a short way of writing it :)